# UIStackView subview contents visible during hiding animation

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation, uistackview

I am using a `UIStackView` for my layout. In that stack view, when I press a button I want to hide one of the subviews. That subview contains a couple buttons and a label. My issue is that during the hide animation, the buttons and label are visible until the vertical space from the subview is fully animated away.

Is there something I can do so that when I call `subview.isHidden = true`, the subview`s contents hide immediately at the beginning of the animation instead of at the very end of the animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a custom `stackView class`.  Use `IBOutlets` in the `class` to reference the buttons/text and write a `function` that hides your outlets when `self.isHidden = true`.  Let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: Yeah that works, I was hoping there was some setting I was missing or something because this seems like a jank way of animating a view on Apple's part.

Comment: yeah, its unfortunate.  Could you please mark the answer as solved?

Answer (score 1):

Besides hiding the buttons and content view with an animation you could try changing the background color from clear on the views inside the stackview to the same color as the background on your view.  This still might not look great but it would be better.

Obviously animation would be something like the code below but give background color on your content views in the stackview a shot.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
            //yourContentHoldingView.alpha = 0
        })
```